# Setting compression method when exporting composer from QGIS to PDF

Tags: qgis, export, print-composer, pdf

I see that export of the composer to PDF in QGIS uses JPEG compression by deafult (my estimate maybe 75-80%, which is not good enough for my maps).

Where can I change this?

Can I set somewhere lossless compression/compaction (e.g. LZW)?

Comment: Why is PNG not an option?

Comment: PDF can maintain many objects as vector. Examples of advantages: a) if necessary, map postprocessing in some graphic software by non-QGIS people gives more capabilities to enlarge the map, or even change some styles; b) texts/labels can be later edited by non-QGIS users in standard PDF editors.

Comment: So far my research, I understand that this is an issue of QT and the functionality could be available in QGIS builds using QT 5.13. This is still not the case with the current QGIS 3.17 release.