# QGIS-3 Controlling PDF Export Image Quality and Compression

Tags: qgis-3, export, pdf, layouts

Is there a way of controlling what image compression or quality is used when exporting a PDF in layout composer?  ArcGIS users will be familiar with the options available under the "Format" tab in the ArcMap "Export Map" menu.

[image]

Is there a similar level of control available in QGIS 3.10?

I found a similar question but it seems dead:
[Setting compression method when exporting composer from QGIS to PDF](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/251633/how-to-set-the-compression-method-when-exporting-composer-form-qgis-to-pdf)

Comment: elcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Please don't re-ask questions, even if they were first asked many years ago; these are your [Options when question is duplicate of one with no/inadequate/old answers](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4010).